# reactjs "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-tsx

I'am new using reactjs and looks like I am following the old tutorial with old version of react router. So the objectives is when I want to edit the user detail, the form must be filled with data of previous user before update. I've already comunicate with the backend using axios and it worked fine, but the problem is in "id = props.match.params.id". and here is my code:

> UserEdit.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { SyntheticEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Wrapper from "../../components/Wrapper";
import { Role } from "../../models/role";

const UserEdit = (props: any) => {
    const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [role_id, setRoleId] = useState('');
    const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    let id: number;


    useEffect(() => {
        (
            async () => {
                const response = await axios.get('roles');

                setRoles(response.data);

                id = props.match.params.id;

                const {data} = await axios.get(`users/${id}`);

                setFirstName(data.first_name);
                setLastName(data.last_name);
                setEmail(data.email);
                setRoleId(data.role_id);
            }
        )()
    }, []);

    const submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        await axios.put('users', {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            role_id
        });

        setRedirect(true)
    }

    if(redirect) {
        return <Navigate to="/users"/>
    }

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <h1 className="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Edit user</h1>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="First Name" defaultValue={first_name}  onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">First Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input className="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"  defaultValue={last_name} onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}  required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Last Name</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" defaultValue={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} required/>
                <label htmlFor="floatingInput">Email Address</label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-floating">
                <select className="form-control" id="floatingRole" placeholder="Role" value={role_id} onChange={e => setRoleId(e.target.value)} required>
                    {roles.map((r: Role) => {
                        return (
                            <option key={r.id} value={r.id}>{r.name}</option>
                        )
                    })}
                </select>
                <label htmlFor="floatingRole">Role</label>
                </div>
                <button className="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>

            </form>
        </Wrapper>

    );
};

export default UserEdit;
```

As you can see in this image below, the data isn't show up and get the error message like this

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

[image: error message]

I really appreciate if anyone wants to help me solve this problem so I can learn further. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer "route props", i.e. no `location`, `history` (*well, now `navigate`*), and no `match`.

Use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook to access the route path parameters.

```
...
import { Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
...

const UserEdit = (props: any) => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('roles');

      setRoles(response.data);

      const { data } = await axios.get(`users/${id}`);

      setFirstName(data.first_name);
      setLastName(data.last_name);
      setEmail(data.email);
      setRoleId(data.role_id);
    })();
  }, []); // <-- add `id` to dependency array if you need to be responsive

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

Comment: @RekhyZakaria Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your params not pass correctly .

Maybe you need to get URL parameters by using **useParams**
like document (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params)
, or check the Router component path format is correct in your React Router version .

In React Router ^v5.3.0 :

```
<Route path="users/:id/edit" />
```

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6` it seems. RRDv5 doesn't export a `Navigate` component.

Comment: Yeah you are right .  Maybe we can wait for more information to solve this problem .

Comment: i'am using react-router version 6, but i already solve the problem with @DrewReese answer. Thankyou for your answer btw

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).